# Saving homepage do not invalidate Full Page Cache

Tags: cms, cache, home

I'm experience this strange issue on EE 1.13.1.0 on the CMS home page only:

I edit the homepage the changes are reflected on `http://MYDOMAIN/home` but not on `http://MYDOMAIN`.
If I clean the cache from backend it still don't see the changes on `http://MYDOMAIN` but I need to remove cache files manually.

The issue is related to the full page cache and looks like the 2 requests (`http://MYDOMAIN` and `http://MYDOMAIN/home`) have different cache.

I can see that `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page` has in the `_afterSave` a call to `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->invalidateType('layout');`

Anyone have same issue ?

Comment: Do you have an external full page cache, which is triggerd through the "Clear magento cache storage" and you clicked the button?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where clearing the cache via the admin did not completely remove the full page cache directory under var. To work around this I added an observer to the event `adminhtml_cache_flush_all` and then when directory storage of cache then I supply removed the folder and all the sub folders.

I am not 100% sure if this is the same issue you are having but it might help you out.